# how to specify the order of attributes of json object in perl?

Tags: json, perl

I'm parsing a table in html file to make it a json file.
I set up  list of attribute names. Each time designated element was found i store it in a perl hash with next attibute name in the list(see code below). Then us JSON module to encode the hash. But the order of each attribute in a object was not  the order they were inserted.

```
    sub scan_line
    {
        my($elem) = @_;   # HTML::Element
        my %result = ();
        my @tds = $elem->find("td");
        my $index = 0;    # of attrnames
        foreach my $td (@tds){
            $result{$attrnames[$index]} = $td->as_text();
            $index++;
        }
        my $text = $json->encode(\%result); 
        print TARGET $text;
    }
```

Are there methods in perl that can specify the order of attribute or add attribute manually like "$jobj->add_attr($attr, $value)"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
my $text = $json->sort_by(sub { $JSON::PP::a cmp $JSON::PP::b })->encode(\%result);
```

Of course you can use <=> instead of cmp or any other sorting function. Note that if your JSON version is below 2.0, you have to explicitly create $json as JSON::PP->new (not JSON->new).

Also be aware that this will decrease performance (and not only of the encode call, but of all $json usages, AFAIU).